# Tensorflow 2.7 GPU Memory not released

Tags: python, tensorflow, memory, gpu

I am currently working on 1D Convolutional Neural Networks for Time Series Classification. Recently, i got CUDA working on my GeForce 3080 (which was a pain itself). However, i noticed a weird behavior when using tensorflow and cuda. After training a model, the gpu memory is not released, even after deleting the variables and doing garbage collection. I tried reseting the tf graph and closing the tf sessions, but the gpu memory stays allocated. This results in cross validation crashing and me having to restart my python environment every time i want to make changes and retrain my model.

After a tideous search, I found out people have been struggling with this 5 years ago. However, I am right now using tf 2.7. I am working on Ubuntu 20.04.3. Some of my colleagues are using windows and are not experiencing these problems. However, it seems like they do not have any issues with models not being able to be retrained because of already allocated memory.

I found the workaround using multiple processes, but wasn't able to get it to work for my model using 10 fold cv.

As the issue has been up for more than 5yrs now and my colleagues not having any problems, I was wondering if I am doing sth. wrong. I think that issue might very likely have been fixed after 5 years, which is why I think my code is the problem here.

Is there any solution / guide for tf 2.7 and memory allocation of the gpu?

Comment: Are you using an interactive python session or are you seeing this memory behavior while running something like python test.py and seeing that process finish and terminate?

Comment: during an interactive python session. memory is not set free after training / in cross validation when fitting multiple data splits one after another to the model when using KFold for example

Comment: I think TF doesn't free memory because it is designed for script mode, not interactive mode. Sorry I don't there's a solution here other than run in script mode.

Comment: Well, but the problem isn't only about memory in the interactive session. The problem occurs when using KFold splits to train models using corss validation. Here, after every split, I need to reset the memory to be able to use multiple splits, but the memory is not released after the splits

Comment: Are you loading your data as numpy arrays or tf.data.Dataset?

Comment: Data is read from several .wav files, then preprocessed and stored in numpy arrays